# Playing with dates in bash: passing variables

Tags: bash, date, scripting

I'm trying to make some calculations with date in bash script but can't find out the right syntax. I get a string from a file that I convert to a date. Then I want to get the date for one and two days ahead. Looking on another StackOverflow posts it looked easy adding days to today date. This is what I am doing now:

```
# Extract date string from file
ctldate=`awk 'NR==8 { print $4 }' a-AC-2015-02-10-120000-g3.ctl`
echo $ctldate
12:00Z10feb2015

# Convert string to date
ctldate2=`date +'%d/%m/%Y' -d $ctldate`
echo $ctldate2
10/02/2015

# Try to add a day, should be 11/02
data1=$(date +'%d/%m/%Y' -d "$ctldate" --date='1 day')
echo $data1
12/02/2015

# Also tried
data1=$(date +'%d/%m/%Y' -d "$ctldate2" --date='1 day')
echo $data1
12/02/2015

# And 
data1=`date +'%d/%m/%Y' -d $ctldate --date='1 day'`
echo $data1
12/02/2015
```

It seems that I'm not properly passing $ctldate var to command and that the base date for calculation is today.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass several `-d` or `--date`, `date` uses the last one. So when you do:

```
date -d "$ctldate" --date='1 day'
```

date will take into account `--date='1 day'` as it's the last `-d`/`--date` argument, and will happily show you tomorrow's date.

Instead you should use:

```
date -d "$ctldate +1 day"
```